# Primitive-wrapper Memory space overhead with generics, In Java

Tags: java, generics, memory, heap-memory

I can't understand primitive-wrapper overhead with generics.

ex.

In Data Structure below, Why 24 byte Overhead isn't added to each item, instead it's added once for `N` inputs.

Question in other way, Why the overall memory space isn't 96N instead of 24 + 72N or why 24 added once.

```
public class GenericMysteryBox<Item> {        //    16(object overhead)
    private Node first;                       //    8 (reference)

    private class Node {                      //    16(object overhead)
                                              //    8 (inner class overhead)
        private Item item;                    //    8 (reference to Integer)
                                              //    24(Integer)
        private Node next;                    //    8 (reference)
        private Node prev;                    //    8 (reference)
    }                                         //    -------
                                              //    24 + 72N  ~ 72N
}
```

Comment: Each `Node` has a reference to the same outer `GenericMysteryBox<Item>`; it's just a reference to the same object, it's not a new outer object for each of them.

Comment: "it's just a reference to the same object", then why object overhead is multiple of N?

Comment: You have overhead for every Node.  Part of that overhead is a reference.  So each `Node` pays the cost of the _reference_, but all those references point to one object which only takes up memory once.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I thought +24 is 24(Integer) at line 7 in code above. you answer, but the truth is 24 for GenericMysteryBox16(object overhead) and Node 8(reference) .. Is that right?

Comment: what?  There aren't any `Integer`s in your code.  But yes, that's more or less correct; 24 is for the `GenericMysteryBox` and its field.

Comment: sorry i didn't say  N Items are an integers. read the comment

Answer (score 0):

Because the class declaration for `Node` (while an inner class) isn't mutable between instances. That is, every instance of `GenericMysteryBox` contains a `Node` that (after [*type erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)) has an `Object` reference and two `Node` references.

This is exactly the same behaviour as if `Node` were declared as a non-private non-inner class (ignoring the visibility of `Node`).

Consider,

```
class Node<Item> {
    private Item item;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;
} 

public class GenericMysteryBox<Item> {   
    private Node<Item> first;            
}
```

Comment: Could you plz explain more?